# Jquery specific action for each button generated by a foreach loop

Tags: php, jquery

how to create specific Jquery action for each button generated by a foreach loop?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#numero").hide();
  $("#shownum").click(function(){
    $("#numero").toggle();
  });
});
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php foreach ($annonces as $key => $annonce) : ?>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" id="shownum"> <span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-earphone" aria-hidden="true"> </span> show/hide</button>
<div id="numero">
  <?php echo $annonce['Annonce']['title'] ;?>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Use a class instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use any `data-attr` or overcomplicating it with `ids`, instead you should be using `class` instead of using the `id`, and properly select the element using jquery traversing.

```
<?php foreach ($annonces as $key => $annonce) : ?>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs shownum_class"> <span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-earphone" aria-hidden="true"> </span> show/hide</button>
<div class="numero_class">
  <?php echo $annonce['Annonce']['title'] ;?>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I have added classes and removed all the `id`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".numero_class").hide();
  $(".shownum_class").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".numero_class").toggle();
  });
});
```

On clicking of `shownum_class`, it will pick the next element `numero_class` which will be specific to every button and then just toggle it.

Answer (score 1):

Your jQuery code selects an ID and IDs should be unique across the whole site. Therefore you cannot use the id attribute in your `<button>` tag. Either add a custom CSS class

```
<button ... class="... my-button"

$(".my-button").click(...
```

or add a name attribute instead

```
<button ... name="shownum" ...

$("button[name=shownum]").click(...
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your php foreach you can generate the buttons so that for the id is:

```js
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" id="shownum<?php echo $value['description'] ?>">
```

At this point your click event can be:

```js
$('[id^="shownum"]').click(function(e){
  $(this).toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
The php and html code :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php $i = 0; foreach ($annonces as $key => $annonce) : ?>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" class="shownum" data-target = <?php echo"'".$i."'"; ?>> <span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-earphone" aria-hidden="true"> </span> show/hide</button>
<div id= <?php echo "numero".$i; ?> class="hideOnLoad" >
  <?php echo $annonce['Annonce']['title'] ; $i++;?>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".hideOnLoad").hide();
  $(".shownum").click(function(){
    $("#numero"+ $(this).data('target')).toggle();
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:-

```
<?php foreach ($annonces as $key => $annonce) : ?>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs shownum"> 
    <span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-earphone" aria-hidden="true">show/hide</spavn> 
  </button>
  <div class="numero">
    <?php echo echo $annonce['Annonce']['title'] ;?>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Js:-

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function(){
    $("div.numero").hide();
    $("button.shownum").click(function(){
        var $this=$(this).next('div.numero');
        $this.toggle(); 
        return false;
      });
  })();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of class attribute instead of id attribute and wrap the whole content inside the container.

```
<?php foreach ($annonces as $key => $annonce) : ?>
    <div class="wrapper">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs show-title" > <span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-earphone" aria-hidden="true"> </span> show/hide</button>
    <div class="title-content">
        <?php echo $annonce['Annonce']['title'] ;?>
    </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Here is the jquery code for toggling it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".title-content").hide();
  $(".show-title").click(function(){
      $(this).parent(".wrapper").find(".title-content").toggle();
  });
});
</script>
```